# How to use NSDate formatter with an array of dates?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdate

I'm trying to generate an array of 30 days from the current date and put them into an array formatted correctly. I currently have a working generater to get 30 days from the current date and put it into an array but I don't know how to use NSDate formatter for an array. I know how to use the formatter for a single item but how can I format all the dates in my array? The format that I would like is (Month Day). Here's my code:

```
NSMutableArray* dates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int numberOfDays=30;
    NSDate *startDate=[NSDate date];
    NSDate *tempDate=[startDate copy];
    for (int i=0;i<numberOfDays;i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@",tempDate.description);
        tempDate=[tempDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60*60*24)];
        [dates addObject:tempDate.description];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",dates);
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use like this,

```
NSMutableArray* dates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int numberOfDays=30;
    NSDate *startDate=[NSDate date];
    NSDate *tempDate=[startDate copy];
    for (int i=0;i<numberOfDays;i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@",tempDate.description);
        tempDate=[tempDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60*60*24)];
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:tempDate];
    tempDate=[dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
    [dateFormat release];

        [dates addObject:tempDate.description];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",dates);
```

Comment: date object always use this format if you want any custom logic with this then you need to convert it in NSDateComponents.Any format you use gives same format for date object but if you change this in string then it simply give what you desired.

Answer (score 3):

i suggest you to give the `NSDate formatter` to your date first and then give those objects to the `NSMutableArray` and  whenever you fetch the object from an array you get the required format.

Hope you get my point...Good Luck!

Comment: It is good way to that, i try to implement this and give an answer by this concept.