# Convert an NSArray of NSDate to an array of formatted dates as strings

Tags: objective-c, ios, for-loop, nsdate

I have an array of non-sequential dates in an NSArray in NSDate format. I need the same set of dates in an array but in NSString formatted as dd/MM. I think I need to loop through reading each date out of the original array converting it to a string and formatting it as I need it, but I can't figure out how to step through the original array.

```
NSError *error2;
NSArray *swim750mArray = [context executeFetchRequest:request2 error:&error2];
if (swim750mArray == nil) {
    NSLog(@"The fetch request2 returned an array == nil");
} else {
    NSLog(@"The fetch request2 returned an array...");
    NSLog(@"%@", swim750mArray);

NSArray *datesAsDates = [swim750mArray valueForKey:@"date"];
NSMutableArray* arrayOfDatesAsStrings = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];

    //SomeCode - Convert the Array of NSDates to a new Array of dates as NSStrings...

      for (int i=0; i<index; i++) {
           //get the date next NSDate from the array as: NSDate *dateAsDate...
           NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
           [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM"];


         NSString *dateAsStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateAsDate];

         [arrayOfDatesAsStrings addObject:dateAsStr];
        }
```

This answer is close to what I need except it doesn't read in from and existing array: [How to use NSDate formatter with an array of dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012381/how-to-use-nsdate-formatter-with-an-array-of-dates)

Please help! Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html)?

```
for (NSDate* dateAsDate in datesAsDates) {
     //get the date next NSDate from the array as: NSDate *dateAsDate...
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM"];

     NSString *dateAsStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateAsDate];

     [arrayOfDatesAsStrings addObject:dateAsStr];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jere named fast enumeration. It also could be done with [block-based enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW19). Also you [should create a formatter once and re-use it](http://twitpic.com/443azs).

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"dd/MM"];

NSMutableArray *datesAsStrings = [NSMutableArray array];
[datesAsDates enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDate *date, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
     NSString *dateString = [dateFormater stringFromDate:date];
     [datesAsStrings addObject:dateString] 
}];
```

if you want to stick with the C-Style for, do

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM"];
for (int i=0; i< [datesAsDates count]; i++) {       
    NSString *dateAsStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[dateAsDate objectAtIndex:i]]; 
    [arrayOfDatesAsStrings addObject:dateAsStr];
}
```

but due to mutation guards, enumeration is preferred.